# Should notifications be removed using removeObserver(self) in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

**Should notification be removed using self in iOS?**

Team mate have registered a notification in `viewWillAppear` and removed in `viewDidDisappear` like,

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidReceiveData(_:)), name: .didReceiveData, object: API.shared)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

While reviewing I have commented and suggested to remove notification with **explicit name** instead of removing with `self` because, I think in future some other notifications might need to be registered in **viewWillLoad** which should not be affected by the call `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)` by accident or by developers mistake. My suggestion was to remove observer using,

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name:.didReceiveData, object: nil)
}
```

Team mates replied that removing with `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)` is perfectly ok because we do not register other notification for now. I was seeking for reference or guideline to convince him, why it is important to remove notification explicitly using name rather by `self`.

**Is there any guideline from Apple about best practice of removing notification observers?**

Comment: I saw something like, we don't need to remove notification observers if we uses weak references inside selector method. I'm not sure about it. Following this thread to know the updates.

Comment: Apple specifically state in the documentation the following : "When removing an observer, remove it with the most specific detail possible. For example, if you used a name and object to register the observer, use removeObserver(_:name:object:) with the name and object."

Answer (score 3):

After iOS 9, no need to remove the observer as iOS would remove observers from de-alloced ViewControllers

Comment: But if removeObserver(self) is used in viewWillDisappear observer will not response even if the view controller exist in stack but not in top. Thats the issue.

Comment: That did not answer the actual question I asked.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is it's not future safe to remove all notification in `viewWillDisappear`. It's not a good practice for an obvious reason but it's not documented.
After iOS 9 it's not necessary to call removeObserver because iOS not try to notify deallocated objects. In your case, you want to listen even if view controller is not visible but present in the navigation stack 
you should do in `deinit`

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    deinit {
     NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name:.didReceiveData, object: nil)
    }
   }
```

Comment: That did not answer the actual question I asked.

Comment: That answer will not convince my team mate. Please read the post to understand the actual problem.

Comment: The thing is it's not future safe to remove all notification in `viewWillDisappear`. It's a practice so it's not documented.